# Insert sysdate using french format(dd/mm/yyyy) to date field in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have table that contain field 'EVT_START_DATE' with datatype is DATE on Oracle.
I want to insert the current date into this field, with french format dd/mm/yyyy.

I did this command line:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH';
```

After that, i tried this block of PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE
v_evt_num VARCHAR(200); 
BEGIN
v_evt_num := 'PC_' || evt_seq.NEXTVAL; 

INSERT INTO event
(EVT_NUM,EVT_CODE_PAY,EVT_CODE_USER,EVT_START_DATE,EVT_MT) 
VALUES 
(v_evt_num,
'129',
'247',
TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
:i_mt);

COMMIT;

dbms_output.put_line('Success.');

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('Fail.');

END;
```

But I get fail message.

Comment: It would help if you share the error message with us. Also, what is i_mt I don't see it declared anywhere. When you use a variable just use the variable name without the : in front of it.
Display the error message instead of just "Fail".

Comment: the error message is : Fail.The i_mt is a input parameter

Comment: Remove the exception handling so you can see the real error.

Comment: After add sqlerrm i get : ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-02063: preceding line from event

Comment: use this:

INSERT INTO event
(EVT_NUM,EVT_CODE_PAY,EVT_CODE_USER,EVT_START_DATE,EVT_MT) 
VALUES 
(v_evt_num,
'129',
'247',
SYSDATE,
i_mt);

Comment: i get this format mm/dd/yyyy of date.

Comment: this how the data is displayed in your session not in the database.
before selecting do:
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY';
OR
select to_char(EVT_START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') from event;

Comment: it works.Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're welcome. but remember a date datatype is stored as a number by oracle, the format you use to insert it doesn't matter, what you want is set the right format when you display the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If EVT_START_DATE is of type DATE, then use just:

```
INSERT INTO event
(EVT_NUM,EVT_CODE_PAY,EVT_CODE_USER,EVT_START_DATE,EVT_MT) 
VALUES 
(v_evt_num,
'129',
'247',
SYSDATE,
:i_mt);
```

whithout using`to_date` function.
Oracle's [SYSDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm) function returns value of type DATE,
 so there is no need to use `to_date` in order to convert it to DATE, bacause it is DATE yet.

> SYSDATE returns the current date and time set for the operating system
>   on which the database resides. **The datatype of the returned value is
>   DATE**

Comment: When i put only SYSDATE, i get this format mm/dd/yyyy of date.
Event i set NLS_LANGUAGE TO french.

Comment: Where do you get this format ? Do you get this date while running `SELECT * FROM event` ?